# Overheating/high CPU usage by Windows VM

Tags: windows, virtualbox, kubuntu

I am running Kubuntu 14.4 as a host and windows 7 in a VirtualBox. The later is using ~30% of my CPU and overheats the CPU to 94°C. This does not seem healthy. What is going on here and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't see how a vm using 30% of CPU is the cause for overheat. Overheat happens under stress conditions with poor HW design / choices. Any system that is properly assembled can handle several hours/days of CPU and GPU high activity. I would ensure first that your system is properly cleaned. If it is a laptop them make sure you don't cover the air entries and exits. some laptops have the air flow entries from the bottom which when the laptop sits on the lap, the air intake is just "disabled"

Comment: @BitsOfNix: The air vents are at the side and seem free of dust. I don't seem to be the only one (though the other is having a Mac): http://kb.parallels.com/en/123268